# Huawei Drive Kit “OUTER_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE” error

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to upload my files using the Huawei Drive Kit Api

I have been following the instructions from the official codelab here: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSDriveKit/index.html#0

but whenever I am trying to upload, I am getting an error in my logs and it says

```
{ "error": { "errorDetail": [ { "domain": "global", "errorCode": "22115002", "reason": 
"OUTER_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE", "description": "Send request to USER failed" } ] }, "code": 500, 
"description": "Internal Server Error" }
```

I could not resolve what might be causing the problem. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please restart the driver Kit and try again.

You can find the switch in **My projects -> Your app -> Project Setting -> Manage APIs**.

Turn it on please if it's turned off. If it's turned on and still not working, try to turn it off and turn it back on once. Idk what is causing this problem but I faced the same problem before and solved it by turning off & back on the switch in from the console.